# WPF DataGrid selecting disabled

Tags: .net, wpf, wpfdatagrid

In VS 2010/.NET 4.0, I have a `List<MyClass>` list of a simple class as such:

```
public class MyClass
{        
    public string String1 { get; set; }
    public string String2 { get; set; }

    public MyClass(string string1, string string2)
    {
        String1 = string1;
        String2 = string2;
    }
}
```

This list is displayed in a WPF `DataGrid` in code behind:

Columns are added first:

```
List<DataGridColumn> cols = ParentClass.GetColumns();
foreach (DataGridColumn dgc in cols)
{
    myDataGrid.Columns.Add(dgc);
}
```

Item source is set next:

```
myDataGrid.ItemsSource = ParentClass.MyClassess;
```

MyClassess is the List

This works fine in a sense that the DG gets populated but it is not possible to select a row in the DataGrid and `DataGrid.SelectedItem` always returns null. The DataGrid registers mouse events but where ever the click occurs no row gets selected as if the DataGrid is disabled...

```
SelectionMode="Single"  
SelectionUnit="FullRow" 
IsReadOnly="False"
```

Does anyone have any idea what is going on here?

TIA

Here is the XAML as requested:

```
<TabItem Header="Sessions" GotFocus="TabSessionsGotFocus">
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.RowDefinitions>                            
                            <RowDefinition Height="*"></RowDefinition>                            
                        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                            <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                        <DockPanel Grid.Row="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Margin="0">
                            <DataGrid x:Name="dgSessions" DockPanel.Dock="Top" IsEnabled="True" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                SelectionMode="Single"  SelectionUnit="FullRow" Background="WhiteSmoke" 
                                AlternatingRowBackground="Gainsboro" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsReadOnly="False"
                                ColumnHeaderHeight="25" RowHeight="21" MouseRightButtonDown="SessionsRightButtonDown" >
                                <DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                                    <ContextMenu x:Name="cmSessions">
                                        <MenuItem x:Name="miSessionActions">
                                            Action
                                        </MenuItem>                                        
                                    </ContextMenu>
                                </DataGrid.ContextMenu>
                            </DataGrid>
                        </DockPanel>
                    </Grid>
                </TabItem>
```

Comment: Given the information above, the DataGrid should work fine (I tried it).  Some other thing is most likely causing this.  Can you post your XAML?

Comment: Saw your XAML.  I tried it out using direct copy paste and it still works fine.  http://i.imgur.com/ItS6V.png.  If you hover over the column-headers, do you get a response?  A couple of things:  1)  maybe something else is disabling the grid?  or 2) something transparent is on top of the grid?  I'm quite certain though that it has nothing to do with how the grid was initialized.

Comment: Is there some Style or ControlTemplate (with x:Key="{x:Type DataGrid}") for DataGrids defined in your application ? Then you would need to add this to your question.

Comment: @karmic: If something transparent was over the grid it wouldn't register click events and it does...
@Simpzon: There is no style for the DataGrid, there is a style targeting DataGridColumnHeader but I get the same result when I comment it out...

Comment: Ok, the problem was that I was loading the DataGrid when it's parent Tab GotFocus event fired and this event was firing every time the DataGrid was clicked on... Not sure if I should close this question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that I was loading the DataGrid when it's parent Tab GotFocus event fired and this event was firing every time the DataGrid was clicked on.